# BSOD Error Code 1a

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod

For the past couple of months I receive a BSOD Error Code 1a about 1-3 times every single day. It feels like the issue happens a lot when i'm using adobe flash, but i'm sure there is probably a more logical reason for the issues. I have tried pulling out and switching all slots of RAM and I still got BSOD. I also had my Motherboard replaced to see if that would solve the issue, but unfortunately none of the above worked. Also along with the blue screening sometimes my cpu will randomly lock up at 100%.

Specs:

- EVGA X58 FTW3 132-GT-E768-TR LGA 1366 Intel X58 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
- ASUS ENGTX580 DCII/2DIS/1536MD5 GeForce GTX 580 (Fermi) 1536MB 384-bit GDDR5
- RAIDMAX HYBRID 2 RX-730SS 730W ATX12V V2.2/ EPS12V SLI Ready CrossFire Ready Modular Power Supply
- Intel Core i7-960 Bloomfield 3.2GHz LGA 1366 130W Quad-Core Desktop Processor BX80601960
- G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 24GB (6 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600 (PC3 12800) Desktop Memory Model F3-12800CL9T2-24GBRL

Comment: Post some more information on the BSOD you relieved. I use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html to get this information for my clients.

Comment: Looking through the large amounts of .dmp nearly all of them are being triggered by "ntoskrnl.exe". Bug Check String displays "MEMORY_MANAGEMENT". Bug Check Code "0x0000001a. Crash Address "ntoskrnl.exe+75c00". I'm not sure what else to include.

Comment: post the first parameter of the bugcheck. This shows which issue you have.

Comment: @God_smetal - Could you export the information to a text file and update your question?

Comment: ntoskrnl.exe is connected to the kernel.  Which means if the kernel is crashing you have a memory problem.  If this follows multiple motherboards then it meas its the memory being used.

Comment: Parameter 1 : 00000000`00041790 seems to be the most common one.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to upload a file here so instead i took a picture of the BluescreenView window and uploaded it to photobucket. Here is the link http://s996.photobucket.com/user/falconpking_godsmetal/media/BSOD_zpsa64aec80.png.html

Comment: @God_smetal use https://pastebin.com or https://gist.github.com

Comment: As remarked in another comment, the memory error can relate to graphic card memory as well. Usually the bsod indicates problem with a key component: cpu, mb, ram or gpu, , so changing graphic card can be tried as well. The most common bsods I'be encountered in the past decade are usually due to graphic card overheating -- typically by a combo of blocked ventilation slots of case and dusty graphics card ventilator.

Answer (score 0):

BSOD 1a could be related to bad RAM.

Download Memtest burn to disk and run for at least 5 hours, if it finds errors then you should replace the RAM and see if that fixes it, but as Ramhound has stated it would be good if we could see the information of the BSOD so we can try and narrow down where the problem lies (could be a softwrae issue)

Answer (score 0):

Error 1a usually is caused by a memory error, with either your graphics card memory or your internal RAM. What I would advise you try to do is open up your computer and remove all but one RAM stick, and then use your computer as you normally would when you would get the error. if you dont get the error on one stick then switch to another one and keep doing this until you find one that does give you the error, then remove that one from your system. if none of the sticks give you that error the problem likely lies in either your processor or your memory controller (and I'm leaning towards the possibility that its your processor).

Now, if all of the RAM sticks get the error its most likely that your problem is in your processor, and the way its managing the RAM storage. I get the idea that this is actually the problem because of the hangups/lockups that you get when your processor goes to 100 percent usage. <s>While this may actually be a problem purely with the processor it also may be a problem that involves your operating system. If possible, get a fresh hard drive and install windows 7 on that, disable all of the other internal hard drives you may have through BIOS, and then try running as you normally would, but on the new hard drive. if this solves your problem then it is definitely on the operating system's end, and the best course of action would be to move all of your files to the new hard drive and work off of that one.</s> **As you mentioned, this solution DID NOT WORK for you, so the information has been deemed nu-necesarry by myself.**

Comment: I havn't had a chance yet to remove the RAM yet and do them one at a time, but I forgot to mention that I did did a fresh install of windows again but it did not fix the issue.

Comment: ah, too bad, when i was experiencing hangups like that re-installation did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

if parameter 1 = 41790 you run into RAM issues:

```
MEMORY_MANAGEMENT (1a)
    # Any other values for parameter 1 must be individually examined.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00041790, The subtype of the bugcheck.
```

> The 41790 code is part of our an internal memory manager code but the
>   bugcheck in my experience has almost always indicated hardware issues
>   (RAM errors).

**Source:**

```
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/68407ce1-7491-4aee-bdef-5ff4bbc56d99/#11ce9f45-7906-4652-9619-a3ad457a87e9
```

So, download [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/) and [check your RAM for errors](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/246994-guide-to-using-memtest86/). Also make sure the RAM timings are fine. Run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to verify that the current RAM timings match with the SPD data.

Comment: Right now I am testing each individual ram stick without memtest, im putting in 1 at a time and running until I either bsod or reach around 6+ hours. I just started today, but I have to do it this way because I need to use my computer during that time. I give an update if I find anything out from it.